# Maui: appsettings.json file not copied to device

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am trying to implement an appsettings.json file with my Maui Android app.
I've followed multiple examples of how to get this to work but I think the issue is the json file is not getting copied to the device.

https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/

I've used Android Studio to browse the Manifest folder on my android device but the file is not there.
I tried creating appsettings.json in the root of the project and also tried in the Resources\Raw.
I tried setting the Build Action to {None, Embedded Resource, Maui Asset, Android Resource}
I've also tried removing "myassembly" in the code below.

```
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("myassembly.appsettings.json");
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();
builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

**Here's how to reproduce this problem.**

I'm using VS2022 17.3.0 Preview 5.0
Create a new .Net Maui App named MauiApp1 for .Net 6.0

Add appsettings.json to the root of the project

Set these properties on appsettings.json:

```
Build Action to "Embedded Resource" 
Copy to Output Directory to "Copy Always"
```

Debug as either Android Emulator or Physical device
for mine I have Android Emulator - Pixel 5
also Zebra Technologies MC93 Android Scan gun

Wait for the application to deploy.  I use Android Studio Device Manager to browse either Emulator or Physical device.

Browse to `/data/data/com.companyname.mauiapp1/files/.__override__`

look for mauiapp1.appsettings.json -- not found

look for appsettings.json -- not found

shouldn't the file be here??

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You've set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. So it won't be a file on the device. It is a resource embedded in the package. I don't know why your attempt to access it as an embedded resource is not working.

Comment: well... since this is a appsettings.json file I thought I would get application settings to be stored in the configuration.  I also tried None, Embedded Resource, Maui Asset, Android Resource.  That would explain why it's not showing as a file.

Comment: I don't know anything about that part. All I know is by those instructions, there won't be a file with that name. Did you do `public MainPage(IConfiguration config)`, then examine/use the `config` object?

Comment: You are correct.  The contents of the appsettings.json file were indeed within the dll.  I may have had a case-sensitivity problem with the namespace as now the code works.  I'm not sure exactly what fixed it but at least I'm not trying to look for a file that doesn't exist.  If you add that as an answer I will mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem and I'm wondering if there was ever a real solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve using the following code:

```
        Stream resourceStream = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"<project_namespace>.appsettings.json");

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(resourceStream);
        return builder.Build();
```